# Error when Attempt to Present ViewController on Button Click But Not Method Fire

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboard

I have a `StartViewController` with a segue set up to a `FinishViewController`.

The `StartViewController` has a button and timer. If the timer runs out it calls the method `finish`. But the user can click the stop button to move to the `FinishViewController`;

If the user clicks the button, `stop`, the `FinishViewController` is loaded up.

If the timer calls the `finish` method I get the error:

> Warning: Attempt to present < FinishViewController: 0x7c15a1d0> on
>   < StartViewController: 0x7c252d20> whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

I don't understand why. The code is literally the same.

Here is the code.

```
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_finished" sender:self];
}

- (void) finish {

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_finished" sender:self];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"prepareForSegue %@", [segue identifier]);

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segue_finished"]) {
        NSLog(@"segue  to finished. ");
        FinishViewController * fvc = (FinishViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;

    }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: It looks like your `finish` method is called when your StartViewController isn't displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you add your timer? You should add it in `viewDidAppear` in `StartViewController` and invalidate it in `viewWillDissapear`. And don't forget to run `performSegue` in main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue_finished" sender:self];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same this issue when i was accidentally presenting the same view controller twice.

Check that it does not call the (stop) function when stop the timer.